# If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=a$ and $g$ is continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x\to c} g(f(x))=g(a)$.

Tags: limits, functions

How do I prove:
if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=a$ and $g$ is continuous at $a$, then $\lim_{x\to c} g(f(x))=g(a)$.

What if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to c} g(f(x))=g(a)$, does this imply that $g$ is continuous at $a$?

I want to learn some strategies used to solve this type of problem.

Comment: Show us your proof so far. For the sake of learning, it's much better to guide you to the answer than hand it over upfront.

Comment: Next time please use MathJaX to typeset equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @AlannRosas I'm unsure of what limit rules I can use here. For the first one, I have lim x->a g(f(x))=g(lim x->a f(x))=g(b), but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: That is quite a trivial one. Note that by definition $f(x)\to a$ at $x\to c$ iff for any sequence $x_n\to c$ we have $f(x_n)\to a$. Also note that a function $g$ is continuous in $a$ if $y_n\to a$ implies $g(y_n)\to g(a)$. Combine these to get your property. Your second statement if wrong. Take $f(x) = 0$. Then $f(x) \to 0$ for $x\to c$ for any $c$, and $g(f(x))=g(0)\to g(0)$ for *any* $g$.

Comment: The first statement can also be proved by the "$\epsilon-\delta$ method".

Comment: What level are you working with? Calculus I? Real analysis?

Comment: @Bonnaduck I'm working with Calculus I

Comment: I've broken down *what* exactly is going on in three simple steps. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

> A wise man once said, "When in doubt, substitute!"

---

Let $y=f(x)$ and see that $y = f(x) \to a$ when $x \to c$, so $$\lim\limits_{x \to c}g(f(x))= \lim\limits_{y \to a} g(y)$$

This works because $g$ is continuous at $y=a$, oh but then that means $$\lim\limits_{y \to a} g(y) = g(a)$$

But wait, $a=\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)$, so $$ g(a) = g\left(\lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x)\right)$$

---

Hence,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to c}g(f(x)) = \lim\limits_{y \to a}g(y)= g(a)=g\left(\lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $\alpha > 0$ 
such that $|x - a| < \alpha \implies |g(x) - g(a)| < \epsilon.$ 
This follows from the definition of a function being continuous at a specific point.

For any $\alpha > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ 
such that $|x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - a| < \alpha.$

However, $|f(x) - a| < \alpha \implies |g[f(x)] - g(a)| < \epsilon.$

**To prove:**

For all $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that 
$|x - c| < \delta \implies |g[f(x)] - g(a)| < \epsilon.$

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is as follows:If $g$ is continuous at $a$, given $\eta>0$, exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $|y-a|< \delta_1$ implies $|g(y) -g(a)| < \eta$. How $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=a$ given $\delta_1>0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|< \delta$ implies $|f(x) -a| < \delta_1$. combining the two definitions you have: given $\eta>0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|< \delta$ implies $|g(f(x)) -g(a)| < \eta$. Then $\lim_{x\to c} g(f(x))=g(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is continuous, then we can pass the limit into the function. So, if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=a$ and $g(x)$ is continuous, then

$$\lim_{x\to c}g(f(x))=g(\lim_{x\to c}f(x))=g(a).$$

In order for $g(f(x))$ to be continuous at $x=c$, we would need $$\lim_{x\to c}g(f(x)) = g(f(c)),$$

but $f(c)$ may not be defined, so $g(f(c))$ may not be defined. For example, consider $f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $g(x)=x$. We have $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=2$, so

$$\lim_{x\to 1}g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)) = g(2) = 2$$

However, $g(f(1))$ does not exist, since $f(1)$ is undefined, which means that $g(f(x))$ is not continuous at $x=1$. Indeed, this is obvious, since $g(f(x))=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$.